# Select a menu item with a submenu and then hide the main menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a mobile mobile menu system.

If you click on 'menu item 4' the main menu items get 'display none' applied to them which is what I want, but then I want to click back on the 'menu item 4' to re-enable them which I can't seem to work out:

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/g3jkgyhy/

```
$("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
    $("#sb-navigation").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#level1').hide();
    }, 500);
    $('.item').css('display', 'block');
  });

$("#submenu").on("click", function(){
    $("#level1").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    var v = $(this).toggleClass("active");
    var j = $('#sb-navigation nav ul li.item');

    if ($('#level1').is(':visible')){
      $(j).css('display', 'none');
      //alert('test');
    }else {
      $(j).css('display', 'block');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/g3jkgyhy/1/

You need to change

```
$("#level1").slideToggle()
```

to

```
$("#level1").slideToggle(function() {
```

slideToggle take this done callback, which is when you need to check for :visible. When you just call slideToggle() and continue with the code, you reach your is:visible check before slideToggle finishes running so the visiblity of #level1 is always true.